# Worday VBA with EOM function not giving a non workday result

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am trying to get the last workday of a month, in relation to a set date -1 month:

Function below returns 30/04/2022 (which is a Saturday), I don't understand why as workday should be returning 31/05/2022 - 1 month, workday = 29/04/2022?

`Arrholidays` is an array of holidays
Report date = 31/05/2022

```vb
PnLD1WS.Cells(i, 159).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(ReportDate, -1), 0, ArrHolidays)
```

Also tried reversed, still gives 30/04/2022 and not 29/04/2022

```vb
PnLD1WS.Cells(i, 159).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth((Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(ReportDate, -1, ArrHolidays)), -1)
```

Comment: Change the 0 to -1, without changing the order like you did with the second example.

Comment: Cheers that works...thought I'd tried changing that but seems like I lost the plot!

Comment: @Gsreg does the -1 apply -1 day ONLY if that date is a holiday?

Comment: Of course not! If you need to keep the original day if it's already a working day, do not apply `WorkDay` in that case.

Comment: @GSerg No I meant, if the DATE -1 month is a non work day, then -1 means it will take -1 day to the nearest workday? Sorry but im confused by argument 2 of the workday function. What I need is the last workday of a month basically.

Comment: It's worded rather clearly: "*The number of nonweekend and nonholiday days before or after start_date. A positive value for days yields a future date; a negative value yields a past date*". So `-1` means stepping 1 working day to the past of the given day, which brings you to the closest working day that is in the past relative to the given date, regardless of whether the given date is itself a working day.

Comment: @Gsreg ok ...so rephrase of my original question: how can I get the nearest workday from a given date?

Comment: Like I [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72546676/worday-vba-with-eom-function-not-giving-a-non-workday-result?noredirect=1#comment128154417_72546676), check if it's already a workday, and if it is, do not apply `WorkDay`?

Comment: PnLD1WS.Cells(i, 159).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(ReportDate, -1) + 1, -1, ArrHolidays) seems to work

Answer (score 1):

Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(ReportDate, -1) + 1, -1, ArrHolidays)

Adding  =WORKDAY(DATE+1,-1)

Checks if given date is working day or not and gives closest workday